# What is the difference between Searches and CV Search Hits

Tags: discussion, jobs

This has confused me a little bit, I'm not entirely sure what the distinction between the two are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the searches is just the total number of searches that employers have executed, whereas the search hits are the number of times queries have return you as a result. It is a bit confusing.

Comment: Ok so the number of searches is not something specific to me?  That makes more sense. It might help if the global stats (like searches and employers) were segregated from my personal stats.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

I clarified the language on the stats to make it more clear.